# Как нарисовать картинку с помощью OpenGl?

Tags: изображения, c++, opengl

Здравствуйте! Не подскажете, как нарисовать картинку с помощью OpenGl?

**Update**

Вроде разобрался, накидал функцию:

```
void window::drawImage(int num, int w, int h, int x, int y){ 
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[num]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(x, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(y, 128.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(x+w, 0, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(y+h, 0, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Только проблема: картинка не корректно отображается

[Вот.](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Ld-b5l8c2J0/VMIHea6vaTI/AAAAAAAAAzI/RIzcITBHVnE/w503-h104-no/Screenshot%2Bfrom%2B2015-01-23%2B12%3A33%3A14.png)

Comment: Если вы пишете под windows, то вам [сюда](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/).

Comment: Нет, мне нужно кроссплатформенно.

Comment: тогда выбирайте программирование с помощью QT, там есть компонент QT opengl.

Comment: Неужели SDL не кроссплатформеный :)

Comment: Если вы уже понимаете, что такое sdl, то вам как раз нужны уроки, которые я предложил в ответе.

Comment: Поэтому с SDL решил перебраться на OpenGl

Comment: sdl это кроссплатформеная библиотека ввода и вывода ака окошки создает, а opengl это одинаковый стандарт программирования графики для всех платформ.